# Measure average bandwidth and latency of program macOS

Tags: networking, mac, performance, bandwidth

I have a program I have made and I want to analyze the performance of said program, specifically the impact of the network connection. The program will send multiple requests to one API (incase that simplifies it) and, prefereably, I would like to analyze the average bandwidth and latency of all the network requests by the program.

I have tried multiple tools but none that fullfills my needs. `nettop` helps me with how much data the program has downloaded, but neither bandwidth nor latency is presented. Similarly, the “Activity Monitor” on macOS can show me the amount of data downloaded and uploaded, along with the number of packets. But it cannot tell me the overall network bandwidth nor latency.

[`nethog`](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) seems to be what I am looking for, but it cannot filter by process on Mac apparently. WireShark cannot filter by proccess either. I have “[iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/)” but it will not show the average bandwidth of the program, only the *current* bandwidth. Even spent a few bucks on “[App Terrain](https://apps.apple.com/nl/app/appterrain/id1570169176?mt=12)” but this cannot show me the average bandwidth either.

Is it really not possible to measure the overall average bandwidth and latency of the network requests of a program on Mac?

Comment: I think the common way to do this would be to use "Xcode Instruments": performance profiling tools built into the IDE.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but "Xcode Instruments" does not show the latency of the connections. Altough, it does show Minimum- and Average round trip time which is somewhat helpful as it can help me calculate the bandwidth. Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious, what tools would you be using for this on other platforms?

Comment: [`nethog`](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs) on Linux seems to be able to report the bandwidth for each process. Personally I have never used such a tool before